# jacobian of a dot product of 2 functions

Tags: vectors, jacobian

take the function $f: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ an a function $g: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ defined via $$ f
\begin{pmatrix}
 x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 x+z^3\\
xyz
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $$ g
\begin{pmatrix}
 s\\
t
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 s^2 + t\\
s+t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
compute the vector  $$ J(g \circ f) \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ , that is the jacobian of the dot product

Comment: I don't see how you can define $g \cdot f$ of a vector $(x,y,z)$ because $g(x,y,z)$ doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean composition $g \circ f$, which does make sense, and for which the Jacobian comes via the product rule?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean! I'm sorry, I'm trying my best with formatting

Comment: Oh ok, then you must be knowing the chain rule, and must be having trouble applying it, is that right?

Comment: I have the dot product = $$
\begin{pmatrix}
 (s^2+t)(x+z^3) + (s^2+t)(xyz)\\
(s+t)(x+z^3) + (s+t)(xyz)
\end{pmatrix} 
$$ is that right? also i am confused how to plug in 1, 2, and 3 if g only has 2 variables

Comment: You are not dealing with the dot product, but with *composition* of functions. For example, if $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^2$ , then $g \circ f(x) = (x^3)^2 = x^6$, for example. Now, try composition of $g,f$ in your example. An aside, do you know the chain rule?

Comment: I do know the chain rule. Do I compute the jacobian of f and g individually and then fo the composition ? or do i take the jacobian of what I had previously commented? Sorry my professor's explanations are really bad so I am super confused

Comment: Yes, you need the Jacobians of $f$ and $g$ individually. But you need to evaluate them at different points. First, can you compute the individual Jacobians for $f$ and $g$ and show me? (The Jacobians will be matrices, and will be functions of $x,y,z$ and $s,t$ for $f$ and $g$ respectively).

Comment: ok so the jacobian of $$ f = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0     & 3z\\
yz  &   xz    & xy
\end{pmatrix} $$ and the jacobian of $$ g = \begin{pmatrix}
2s & 1\\
1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: (I can see you are having trouble with gaps in the matrices, you will pick it up, that is fine) Yes, the Jacobian in the second is fine. The Jacobian in the first is all right, except in the top right, you should have $3z^2$ instead of $3z$. Ok, now I can answer the question.(Also, the spaces are very good now. I have up voted your question, I like the fact you are taking interest).

Comment: ok so i plug in 1, 2 and 3 into f for x,y,z?

Comment: I think I am in a position to carry our chat into my answer, which should come in five minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have no trouble bar silly mistakes in computing the Jacobian. More precisely, we have :
$$
Df(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3z^2 \\
zy&xz&xy
\end{pmatrix} ; 
Dg(s,t) = \begin{pmatrix}
2s & 1 \\
1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, the chain rule is the following : (with variables $a,b,c$ to avoid confusion)
$$
D(g \circ f)(a,b,c) = Dg(f(a,b,c)) \times Df(a,b,c)
$$

So, in steps , given a point $(a,b,c)$ :

- Find $f(a,b,c)$.
- Find $Df$ evaluated at $(a,b,c)$, and $Dg$ evaluated at $\color{green}{f(a,b,c)}$ , and *not* $\color{red}{(a,b,c)}$.
- Multiply them as matrices, in the order specified in the formula.

For example, you have $(a,b,c) = (1,2,3)$. We find that $f(1,2,3) = (28,6)$.

Now, we have $Df(1,2,3) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 27 \\
6 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$.

We also have $Dg(28,6) = \begin{pmatrix}
56&1\\1&1
\end{pmatrix}$

And therefore, multiplying them in that order gives 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
56&1\\1&1
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 27 \\
6 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
62 & 3 & 1514\\
7 & 3 & 29
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is the answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, please keep the steps in mind.